# RegEx for first letters that MIGHT precede @

Tags: regex, actionscript

I'm looking for the regex to capture the first letters of a string that *might* be an email address. If it is an email address, just the first letter of words before the @. In other words, the first letter of words that may or may not be followed by a @, and if there is an @ present, ignore the text after it. For example (captured letters in bold and explanation given on the first 3):

- **f**irst.**l**ast (captures f and l when no @ is present)
- **f**irst (captures f)
- **f**irst.**l**ast@exampledomain.com (captures f and l but stops capturing when it encounters an @)
- **f**irst@example.com
- **f**irst@sub.example.com
- **f**irst.**m**iddle.**l**ast@example.com

The regex I have so far is `/\b[a-z](?=.*@)/g` but it only works if there is an @ present.

For background, I'm trying to capitalize the first letter of names used in an email address. Anything after the @ should be left as is. That's why I really just need to capture lowercase letters at the start of a word. I'm using actionscript which uses the same conventions as javascript.

SOLUTION:

Since actionscript doesn't support lookbehind, I ended up using this code to return the string with capitalized results of the regex:

```
var pattern:RegExp;
if(string.indexOf("@") == -1) {
    // no @ in string, so just find first letters of words
    pattern = /\b[a-z]/g;
} else {
    // @ exists so just find first letters of words before @
    pattern = /\b[a-z](?=.*@)/g;
}
// return the string, capitalizing the results of the regex
return string.replace( pattern, function():String { return String(arguments[0]).toUpperCase(); } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way for you to do this is to do 2 searches:

The first would be to capture everything before `@` character with:

```
[^@]+
```

then to search through THAT list to capture all the first letters:

```
\b[a-z]
```

I of course don't know how you are actually implementing any of this (posting some real code may help me help you, FYI) but this seems to be the best option.

If you were using ANY other engine, I would suggest this:

```
(?<!.*@.*)\b[a-z]
```

which makes use of lookbehinds, but alas, JS does not have lookbehinds.

Comment: \b[a-z](?=.*@?) matches first letters even after the @ sign. Is that regex what you were suggesting?

Comment: i think im going to need a tad bit of clarification on what you want. can you maybe add a few more examples as well as some examples of things that wont match and also what your match should look like?

Comment: I edited to add some clarity. I'm trying to capture the first letter of words but stop capturing if/when it finds an @.

Comment: ahh okay. and what engine/language are you using?

Comment: actionscript (uses javascript flavor of regex)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help to you.

```
^([a-zA-Z]{1})[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.?([a-zA-Z]{1})?
```

https://regex101.com/r/eL3dK4/1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your captures work. Maybe this is closer/useful.

```
^([A-Za-z])[^.@]*(?:[.]([A-Za-z])[^.@]*)*@
```

Or maybe you just want to cap the matches at three?

```
^([A-Za-z])[^.@]*(?:[.]([A-Za-z])[^.@]*)?(?:[.]([A-Za-z])[^.@]*)?@
```

https://regex101.com/r/eL3dK4/1#javascript

Comment: This is in actionscript, which follows javascript conventions.